# Pass parameter of procedure as variable to trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table named artist_log & it has following structure

```
[action_type     char(6)]
[artist_id       int]
[mod_date        datetime    default current_timestamp]
```

Created a procedure as mentioned below:

```
create procedure update_artists 
    @m_artist_id int, 
    @m_place_of_birth varchar(60)
as
begin
    update artists
    set place_of_birth = @m_place_of_birth 
    where artist_id = @m_artist_id ;
end ;
```

and executing it with following statement

```
execute update_artists 2019, 'Delhi' ;
```

I want to create a trigger `UPDT_LOG` which will add a record to table `artist_log` with values as `UPDATED` and value of `artist_id` column should be same as parameter viz. `@m_artist_id` which was passed to execute above mentioned procedure. Any help?

Comment: `UPDATED` is too long for your `action_type char(6)` column ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to 'pass' parameters to a trigger. Whatever rows you update, you can access using the DELETED and INSERTED tables in the body of the trigger.

```
create trigger updt_log on artists for update as
insert into artist_log (action_type, artist_id)
select 'UPDATE', artist_id
from inserted
```

This is the simplest form of a trigger. If artist_id can be updated by design, then you'll have to handle that case as well.